# Geodistance value in Elasticsearch Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following model:

```
# Place of the system
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, :description, :address, :discount, :user, :latitude, :longitude, presence: true

  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy

  mapping do
    indexes :location, type: 'geo_point'
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json.merge location: { lat: lat, lon: lon }
  end

  #def location
    #[lat, lon]
  #  { lat: lat, lon: lon }
  #end

  def self.search()
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        track_scores: true,
        query: {
          match_all: {}
        },
        sort: [{
          '_geo_distance' => {
            location: {
              lat: 54.3815231323242,
              lon: 48.6007232666016
            },
            'order' => 'asc',
            'unit' => 'km'
          }
        }]
      }
    )
  end
end

Place.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Place.index_name rescue nil

# Create the new index with the new mapping
Place.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
  index: Place.index_name,
  body: { settings: Place.settings.to_hash, mappings: Place.mappings.to_hash }

# Index all article records from the DB to Elasticsearch
Place.import
```

This code works, i.e. I can get sorted places using `Place.search().records.to_a`. Now I need also to get distance between location I set in 'sort' and each place (I need to show this value in my mobile app). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last attribute from `sort` field inside record is `distance` from point you have passed, for example:

```
@places = Place.search.results
# places = Array of Hash, that contains key sort
# places.last is lets say last place
# places.last[:sort] is Hash containing params
# places.last[:sort].last is distance from location
```

This is example, not how you do it

use case

```
@places.each do |place|
  place["sort"] # hash containing sort details
  place["sort"].last # contains distance
  place["sort"].last.round(2) # because distance is like 12.23488123
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work. NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Results:0x007f8c947b68d0>